# How to use Python to find all isbn in a text file?

Tags: python, parsing

I have a text file `text_isbn` with loads of ISBN in it. I want to write a script to parse it and write it to a new text file with each ISBN number in a new line.

Thus far I could write the regular expression for finding the ISBN, but could not process any further:

```
import re
list = open("text_isbn", "r")
regex = re.compile('(?:[0-9]{3}-)?[0-9]{1,5}-[0-9]{1,7}-[0-9]{1,6}-[0-9]')
```

I tried to use the following but got an error (I guess the list is not in proper format...)

```
parsed = regex.findall(list)
```

How to do the parsing and write it to a new file (output.txt)?

Here is a sample of the text in `text_isbn`

```
Praxisguide Wissensmanagement - 978-3-540-46225-5
Programmiersprachen - 978-3-8274-2851-6
Effizient im Studium - 978-3-8348-8108-3
```

Comment: Post a snippet of `text_isbn` file in the question body and your regular expression as well.

Comment: You're applying `regex.findall` on an open file handle, whereas it's expecting a string. Try calling `open(...).read()` first.

Comment: Can't you just split the lines on the first `-`?

Comment: Right, I could also split at the first `-`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
import re

isbn = re.compile("(?:[0-9]{3}-)?[0-9]{1,5}-[0-9]{1,7}-[0-9]{1,6}-[0-9]")

matches = []

with open("text_isbn") as isbn_lines:
    for line in isbn_lines:
        matches.extend(isbn.findall(line))
```

Comment: With the regex expression taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381514/regular-expression-for-an-isbn-13

Comment: *cough cough* shadowing the `input` builtin *cough cough*

Comment: Just one piece missing: writing to a new text file... Apart from that, it works..

Comment: You have a list, write it yourself ;)

Comment: Alright, will try to. But `re.compile` throws out an error (2.7):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression

Comment: Your regex isn't valid for python then?

Comment: Well, the regex from the answer seems wrong. When I use the regex from my question with the script from the answer, I get what I want...

Answer (score 0):

try this regex (from [regular expression cookbook](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/regular-expressions/9780596802837/4dot-validation-and-formatting/id2990038) ):

```
import re
data = open("text_isbn", "r")
regex = "(?:ISBN(?:-1[03])?:? )?(?=[-0-9 ]{17}$|[-0-9X ]{13}$|[0-9X]{10}$)(?:97[89][- ]?)?[0-9]{1,5}[- ]?(?:[0-9]+[- ]?){2}[0-9X]$"

for l in data.readlines():
    match = re.search(regex, l)
    isbn = match.group()
    outfile.write('%s\n' % isbn)
```

tested with your sample data. assume that each line contain only one isbn number

Comment: Thanks for that answer. It works as well, but I marked the first answer, but yours is good and valid as well...