# JavaScript Class Getter/Setter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

is there a way to listen for a property call on a JavaScript Class

for example when i go something like this:

```
myForm =  new Form();

myForm.name = 'Name';
```

-> when i set the name i dont only want to set the property but i also want to update my Vuex store.
 Same thing with `get` i would like to read from Vuex store.

I knoew there are thins like Proxy but for this i need to wrap my Class with a Proxy object. Not so sure if i like this.

```
module.exports = new Proxy(new Form({}), {
    get (receiver, name) {
        console.log('getting property from Vuex Store');
    }
});
```

What i need is something like this:

```
module.exports = class Form {

//this should be triggered when form.something
get(property) {
return this[property];
}

//this should be triggered when from.something = 'something'
set(property, value) { 
return this[property] = value;
}
};
```

it there a best practice for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript getters and setters for dummies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies)

Comment: @notgiorgi, It's not a duplicate. The OP asks about setting getters and setters for every property, even those that are not defined.

Comment: Don't use a proxy when you know the names of your getters/setters beforehand.

Comment: @StefanOctavian That's not clear from the question at all?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Javascript supports [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

```js
class Form{
  set foo(val){
    console.log("setting foo")
    this.fooValue = val;
  }
  
  get foo(){
     console.log("getting foo");
     return this.fooValue;
  }
}

let frm = new Form();
frm.foo = "bar";
console.log(frm.foo);
```

You could make this more dynamic by writing a `withGetterSetter` method which wraps each property of an object with a getter/setter.

```js
var form = {
  a: "aValue",
  b: "bValue"
}

function withGetterSetter(obj){
   var keys = Object.keys(obj);
   var result = {};
   
   for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
       var key = keys[i];
       result[key+"_internal"] = obj[key];
       (function(k){
         Object.defineProperty(result,k, {
          get:function() {
            console.log("getting property:",k);
            return this[k + "_internal"];
          }, 
          set: function(x) { 
            console.log("setting property:",k);
            this[k + "_internal"] = x 
          }
         });
       })(key)
   }
   return result;
}

var setterObj = withGetterSetter(form);
console.log(setterObj.a);
setterObj.a = "updated";
console.log(setterObj.a);
```

It works by copying each property `p` to a new object with `p_internal` and creating a dynamic get/set for the original property name.

Comment: My guess is that OP wants some generic getter/setter for all properties at once.

Comment: but like this i would need to set up a setter/getter for every property?

edit: @dfsq yap

Comment: @therabbityouknow how many properties do you have?? How much extra work is it to wrap each?

Comment: i mean if i had to possibility to define the setters and getters in my constructor for all my fields that the form contains , guess it would be fine. I could call `new Form(fields)`. The only thing is it should by dynamic.

Comment: defineProperty only works with objects right? Hmm ill give this a try. Thank you.

Comment: @therabbityouknow you can also use same approach with you class, not only objects