# How do you change class constructor intial values?

Tags: javascript, class

I define a class as follows:

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.age = 60;
  }
  showAge() {
    return console.log(this.age);
  }
}

const mark = new Person();
mark.showAge();  //60
```

How do I change `this.age` that the object mark will initialize with from 60 to another number without simply assigning a new value in the constructor?

The idea is to then create new objects from the class which all instantiate with this new value and not 60 for `this.age`.

Comment: you can pass the age into the constructor `new Person(60);` and then assign it in your constructor: `constructor(age) { this.age = age;}`

Comment: watch this [JavaScript Class Getter/Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49895210/5385135)

Comment: Pass the values to the constructor: `constructor(age) { this.age = age; }` and then create a new object as: `new Person(23)` or `new Person(60)`, etc.